# Visual Studio 2008 connector/NEt Error> Failed to add relations >Unexpected error

Tags: mysql, database-connection, visual-studio-2008-db

I use a database for a website and a local program in C# (Visual Studio 2008). I downloaded the API connector/NET for mysql database. I setted the connection (Connection succeed) but, when i setted what data i'm supposed to take, i take only the tables. But when i clicked OK, an error message appear > `Failed to add relations > Unexpected error.`

In my Website, i use this database and it works very well. I use innoDB relations (for the website). in the .xsd file (local program) There is only one link between two tables. The others are created but not linked with each others.

How can I make the connection of a mysql database to a visual studio (C#) local program

Thanks to help me.

PS . Here is my mysql database

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.3.9
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Serveur: localhost
-- Généré le : Mer 17 Août 2011 à 22:48
-- Version du serveur: 5.5.8
-- Version de PHP: 5.3.5

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Base de données: `test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `adresse`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adresse` (
  `idAdresse` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `numRue` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `rue` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ville` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `postal` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAdresse`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Contenu de la table `adresse`
--

INSERT INTO `adresse` (`idAdresse`, `numRue`, `rue`, `ville`, `postal`) VALUES
(1, 4256, 'de la Vallee', 'Laval', 'H8A1J7'),
(2, 121, 'du Coin', 'Laval', 'N6A1B8'),
(4, 5, 'rue du Ranch', 'Laval', 'D1C0V8');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `listepatient`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listepatient` (
  `idListeP` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `idPatient` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPatient`,`idListeP`),
  KEY `idListeP` (`idListeP`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Contenu de la table `listepatient`
--

INSERT INTO `listepatient` (`idListeP`, `idPatient`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `materiel`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `materiel` (
  `idMateriel` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `bidon` int(99) NOT NULL,
  `idProduit` int(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idMateriel`),
  KEY `idProduit` (`idProduit`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Contenu de la table `materiel`
--

INSERT INTO `materiel` (`idMateriel`, `type`, `bidon`, `idProduit`) VALUES
(1, '', 40, 2),
(2, '', 75, 5);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `medicament`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `medicament` (
  `idMedic` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `marque` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `typeMed` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `idProduit` int(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idMedic`),
  KEY `idProduit` (`idProduit`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Contenu de la table `medicament`
--

INSERT INTO `medicament` (`idMedic`, `marque`, `typeMed`, `idProduit`) VALUES
(1, 'Tylenol', 'gelule', 1),
(2, 'Glaxal', 'Ongant', 3),
(3, 'Benylin', 'Sirop', 4);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `panier`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `panier` (
  `idPanier` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `idProduit` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `qte` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPanier`,`idProduit`),
  KEY `idProduit` (`idProduit`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Contenu de la table `panier`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `patient`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `patient` (
  `idPatient` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sexe` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `anniv` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `assurance` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `numDossier` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `idPersonne` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPatient`),
  KEY `idPersonne` (`idPersonne`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Contenu de la table `patient`
--

INSERT INTO `patient` (`idPatient`, `sexe`, `anniv`, `assurance`, `numDossier`, `idPersonne`) VALUES
(1, 'M', '1945-08-17', 40, 'GG450817', 2),
(2, 'M', '1993-01-20', 0, '', 3),
(3, 'M', '1987-03-26', 30, '', 4);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `personne`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `personne` (
  `idPersonne` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `prenom` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPersonne`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Contenu de la table `personne`
--

INSERT INTO `personne` (`idPersonne`, `nom`, `prenom`) VALUES
(1, 'Levesque', 'Jacques'),
(2, 'Gougeon', 'Gaston'),
(3, 'Kostopoulios', 'Andrew'),
(4, 'Lamarche', 'Eric');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `produit`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `produit` (
  `idProduit` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `descr` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `prix` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `qte` int(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProduit`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Contenu de la table `produit`
--

INSERT INTO `produit` (`idProduit`, `nom`, `descr`, `prix`, `qte`) VALUES
(1, 'Tylenol Extra-Fort', 'Medicament soulageant les maux quotidiens', '15.99', 107),
(2, 'Bequille Jumbo', 'Support pouvant supporter jusqu''a 350 lbs', '75.99', 10),
(3, 'Cortico-Steroide', 'Ongant faisant disparaitre les rougeurs de la peau', '20.99', 60),
(4, 'Sirop Benylin', 'Sirop pour contrer les allergies saisonnieres', '17.99', 29),
(5, 'Ceinture Lombaire', 'Ceinture supportant le dos du au douleur de cette region', '79.99', 5);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `specialiste`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `specialiste` (
  `login` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `profession` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `idListeP` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idPanier` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idPersonne` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`login`),
  KEY `idListeP` (`idListeP`),
  KEY `idPanier` (`idPanier`),
  KEY `idPersonne` (`idPersonne`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Contenu de la table `specialiste`
--

INSERT INTO `specialiste` (`login`, `password`, `profession`, `idListeP`, `idPanier`, `idPersonne`) VALUES
('j.levesque', 'hulk', 'Medecin Generaliste', 1, 1, 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `telephone`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `telephone` (
  `idTel` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `typeTel` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `ind` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `quartier` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `num` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTel`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Contenu de la table `telephone`
--

INSERT INTO `telephone` (`idTel`, `typeTel`, `ind`, `quartier`, `num`) VALUES
(1, 'cellulaire', 450, 315, 3105),
(2, 'maison', 450, 214, 6462),
(4, 'maison', 450, 679, 1087),
(5, 'maison', 301, 139, 4285);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `telpers`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `telpers` (
  `idPersonne` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `idTel` int(100) NOT NULL,
  KEY `idPersonne` (`idPersonne`),
  KEY `idTel` (`idTel`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Contenu de la table `telpers`
--

INSERT INTO `telpers` (`idPersonne`, `idTel`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 2),
(4, 4),
(1, 5);

--
-- Contraintes pour les tables exportées
--

--
-- Contraintes pour la table `adresse`
--
ALTER TABLE `adresse`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `adresse_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idAdresse`) REFERENCES `personne` (`idPersonne`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Contraintes pour la table `listepatient`
--
ALTER TABLE `listepatient`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `listepatient_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idListeP`) REFERENCES `specialiste` (`idListeP`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `listepatient_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idPatient`) REFERENCES `patient` (`idPatient`);

--
-- Contraintes pour la table `materiel`
--
ALTER TABLE `materiel`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `materiel_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idProduit`) REFERENCES `produit` (`idProduit`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Contraintes pour la table `medicament`
--
ALTER TABLE `medicament`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `medicament_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idProduit`) REFERENCES `produit` (`idProduit`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Contraintes pour la table `panier`
--
ALTER TABLE `panier`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `panier_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idPanier`) REFERENCES `specialiste` (`idPanier`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `panier_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idProduit`) REFERENCES `produit` (`idProduit`);

--
-- Contraintes pour la table `patient`
--
ALTER TABLE `patient`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `patient_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idPersonne`) REFERENCES `personne` (`idPersonne`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Contraintes pour la table `specialiste`
--
ALTER TABLE `specialiste`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `specialiste_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idPersonne`) REFERENCES `personne` (`idPersonne`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Contraintes pour la table `telpers`
--
ALTER TABLE `telpers`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `telpers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idPersonne`) REFERENCES `personne` (`idPersonne`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `telpers_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idTel`) REFERENCES `telephone` (`idTel`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

HERE MY CONNECTION CODE

Class:

```
<?php
    Class Connexion{
        function open(){
            $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            if (!$con)
            {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                return '';
            }
            else return $con;
        }//OPEN

        function close($con){  mysql_close($con);  }//CLOSE
    }//Connexion
?>
```

The connection :

```
<?php 
    require('manip/connexionClass.php');
    $conn = new Connexion();
    $con = $conn->open();
    if($con){
                    mysql_select_db("test",$con);
        $query = "SELECT SUM(`panier`.`qte`) 
                        FROM `panier`
                        WHERE `panier`.`idPanier` = (
                            SELECT `idPanier`
                            FROM `specialiste`
                            WHERE `login` = '".$_SESSION["login"]."'
                        )";

        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result)==0){ $nb = 0;    }
        else{
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $_SESSION["nbArticle"] = $row["SUM(`panier`.`qte`)"];
            }
            $nb = $_SESSION["nbArticle"];
        }
    $conn->close($con);  //CLOSE CONNECTION
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the code where you are connecting to the database in the website?  The database itself may not be the problem, but how you are making the relations, and how you are trying to access the data in the code.

Comment: This looks like the question is mis-tagged. It doesn't look like C#... it looks like this should be tagged with PHP, since your code is in PHP, not in C#.  Where is the VisualStudio / C# code?

Comment: The only thing i want to do is to import and use my mysql database.. I follow the instructions.. but it doesnt work (in Visual Studio 2008 C#) Error: Failed to add relations > Unhandled error

Comment: The code up there is my connection in my website.. but i want to use mysql databse to my local program